# Disable 64 bit in Cocos2d v3 - how to do it with debug builds

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

So here I am using Cocos2d v3, with a game 90% done. It seems that for business reasons I might have to include an external framework which does not support arm64 and there's not much I can do about it, except maybe go back to Cocos2d v2.1 (I'm not doing that). Or is there?

I tried removing arm64 from valid architectures, and am able to build and run even on iPhone 5s. **Somehow I don't get it to compile in debug yet - what option could be preventing this?** 
I get lots of errors like: /Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libcocos2d.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7):

**Update**: I found out what was wrong. With an iPhone 5s plugged in and "Build active architecture only", Xcode only wanted to build arm64. This worked as long as I disconnected the iPhone 5s. And I needed to disable Build active architecture for the linked targets of cocos2d and chipmunk respectively, too.
So the changes I did was:

- Remove arm64 from valid architectures in my game target
- Disable build active architecture for all three targets: my game, cocos2d, chipmunk

Still remains to be seen if there are any other pitfalls doing this.

Comment: On the discussion side of things, see this thread over at cocos2diphone forums: http://forum.cocos2d-iphone.org/t/disable-64-bit-arm64/13726 I am asking if there are any known or suspected pitfalls going down the disable 64 bit path.

Comment: I'd recommend leaving valid architectures as it is, and changing the build architectures instead.  What this does is says "build it with X architectures, but allow it to run on Y [valid architectures]".  An iPhone 5S has no trouble running armv7s apps (since arm64 can execute armv7s and even armv7).